# How to validate that there are only digits in a string?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I'm working on a project where I need to read mostly integers from the user through the console. In order to avoid someone entering non-digit characters I thought about reading the input as a string, checking there are only digits in it, and then converting it to an integer. I created a function since I need to check for integers several times:

```
bool isanInt(int *y){
    string z;
    int x;
    getline(cin,z);
    for (int n=0; n < z.length(); n++) {
        if(!((z[n] >= '0' && z[n] <= '9') || z[n] == ' ') ){
            cout << "That is not a valid input!" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    istringstream convert(z); //converting the string to integer
    convert >> x;
    *y = x;
    return true;
}
```

When I need the user to input an integer I'll call this function. But for some reason when I make a call tho this function the program doesn't wait for an input, it jumps immediately to the for-loop processing an empty string. Any thoughts? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just do `cin >> z` instead of `getline`. `x` is then `z.length()`.

Comment: If you really want to read an integer, you can ask C++ to do the checks for you by simply coding:   `int my_int; if (std::cin >> my_int)` ...got an int...`; else` ...not an int or EOF...

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways to test a string for only numeric characters. One is

```
bool is_digits(const std::string &str) {
    return str.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::all_of
#include <cctype>    // for std::isdigit

bool all_digits(const std::string& s)
{
  return std::all_of(s.begin(), 
                     s.end(), 
                     [](char c) { return std::isdigit(c); });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the string in a try/catch block so that if the cast fails you it would raise an exception and you can write whatever you want in the console.

For example:

```
  try
  {
    int myNum = strtoint(myString);
  }
  catch (std::bad_cast& bc)
  {
     std::cerr << "Please insert only numbers "<< '\n';
  }
```

Comment: A custom function to cast string into ints

Answer (score 2):

Character-classification is a job typically delegated to the `ctype` facets of a locale. You're going to need a function that takes into account all 9 digits including the thousands separator and the radix point:

```
bool is_numeric_string(const std::string& str, std::locale loc = std::locale())
{
    using ctype = std::ctype<char>;
    using numpunct = std::numpunct<char>;
    using traits_type =  std::string::traits_type;

    auto& ct_f  = std::use_facet<ctype>(loc);
    auto& np_f = std::use_facet<numpunct>(loc);

    return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [&str, &ct_f, &np_f] (char c)
    {
        return ct_f.is(std::ctype_base::digit, c) || traits_type::eq(c, np_f.thousands_sep())
                                                 || traits_type::eq(c, np_f.decimal_point());
    });
}
```

Note that extra effort can go into making sure the thousands separator is not the first character.

Answer (score -2):

try another way like cin.getline(str,sizeof(str)), and str here is char*. I think ur problem may be cause by other functions before calling this function. Maybe u can examine other parts of ur codes carefully. Breakpoints setting is recommended too.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

Always use off-the-shelf functions. Never write alone.
I recommend 
[std::regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex)

Enjoy.